# Geometry Nodes + Mesh Deform modifier stack not rendering

Tags: rendering, modifiers, geometry-nodes

I have a geometry nodes setup, simply inputing objects in a collection, realising the instances, and then feeding that through the geometry nodes output, essentially merging all the objects into one object, while still being able to modify the objects in the collection.

I've added a Mesh Deform Modifier after the Geometry Nodes modifier with dynamic checked and bound it to a simple mesh for deformation.
The deformation works in the viewport, but when I Render Image, the result doesn't show the deformation from the *Mesh Deform*, works in the viewport, not with *Render Image*.

I've tried to replicate it in another scene, with different geometry in the collection used by the geometry nodes and a different mesh used for the *Mesh Deform*, and it works as expected, the *Mesh Deform* modifier effect renders fine.

Anybody know why this might be happening?

Comment: A likely explanation would be some modifiers with different render and preview settings-- probably, a subdivision modifier with different render/preview iteration counts.  When it renders and uses the higher iterations, the mesh topo changes and the bind is no longer valid.  Can't confirm that suspicion without a file though.

Comment: I think @Nathan is probably on to this one.. please give us an illustration of a simple case, including the modifier stack?

Comment: Thanks Nathan, it was pretty obvious when I looked at it from the right angle, so thank you. Some of the objects in the collection had subdivision surface modifiers applied to them, with different resolutions for view and render. The Mesh Deform modifier wants points to stay the same after binding to the deforming mesh, throws an error when there's an unexpected number of points, which won't have shown up in the viewport, or viewport render, but will have thrown it when rendering an image or animation.